# Google Drive API 401 when trying to download a file

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I'm using the [google-api-php-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) to get the URL for a document on my Google Drive. The URL works correctly when I paste it into my browser and I can download the file.

However, in my PHP app I always get a 401. Here's my code:

```
private function _get_document_contents($url)
{
    // prepare opts
    $opts = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'GET',
            'header' => "Gdata-version: 3.0\r\nAuthorization: Bearer " . $this->_token . "\r\n"
        )
    );

    // get the doc
    return file_get_contents($url . '&exportFormat=html&format=html', false, stream_context_create($opts));
}
```

I've tried changing `Bearer` to `OAuth` (that's what OAuth 2.0 playground uses) but both fail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah the problem seems to be that I'm using the old Google Docs API and should migrate over to the Google Drive SDK. D'oh!